# Elasticsearch sorting using java API

Tags: elasticsearch, java

I am trying to sort my document based on totalEmployee field, where index is **index_db** , the type is **departments** and a field is **totalEmployee**

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();
            SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("index_db").setTypes("departments")
                    .addSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("totalEmployee").order(SortOrder.ASC)).setQuery(qb)
                    .setSize(100).execute().actionGet();
            for(SearchHit hits :response.getHits()) {
                System.out.print("id = "+hits.getId());
                System.out.println(hits.getSourceAsString());
            }
```

But I am getting error :

`Exception in thread "main" Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[q9B7Qs-DSXWC14pjc5zlNg][index_db][0]: RemoteTransportException[[elasticsearch_node][10.64.216.92:9375][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested:`

`IllegalArgumentException[Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [totalEmployee] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.]; }{[q9B7Qs-DSXWC14pjc5zlNg][index_db][1]: RemoteTransportException[[elasticsearch_node][10.64.216.92:9375][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [totalEmployee] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.]; }{[q9B7Qs-DSXWC14pjc5zlNg][piyush_db][2]: RemoteTransportException[[elasticsearch_node][10.64.216.92:9375][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [totalEmployee] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.]; }{[q9B7Qs-DSXWC14pjc5zlNg][piyush_db][3]: RemoteTransportException[[elasticsearch_node][10.64.216.92:9375][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [totalEmployee] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.]; }{[q9B7Qs-DSXWC14pjc5zlNg][piyush_db][4]: RemoteTransportException[[elasticsearch_node][10.64.216.92:9375][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [totalEmployee] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.]; }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As totalEmployee was analyzed field, elastic requries field data value as true to perform sort operation. Instead you can use totalEmployee.keyword to achieve desired results.

Below is the working code.

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();

SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("index_db").setTypes("departments")
                    .addSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("totalEmployee.keyword")
                    .order(SortOrder.ASC)).setQuery(qb)
                    .setSize(100).execute().actionGet();

for(SearchHit hits : response.getHits())
{
     System.out.print("id = " + hits.getId());
     System.out.println(hits.getSourceAsString());
}
```

Comment: This does not respect accentuation

Answer (score 0):

Finally , I got the answer of my above query. The problem was due to dynamic mapping during indexing in Elasticsearch. Better use your own mapping and do sorting on **long** type field (In my case I was trying to sort on the basis of **keyword**(string) field type).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify sort options in the search request:

```java
SearchRequest request = SearchRequest.of(req -> req
  .index(indexName)
  .query(query)
  .sort(SortOptions.of(so -> so
    .field(f -> f
      .field(sortField)
      .order(SortOrder.Asc)
    )
  ))
);
```